# Running a rake tasks that runs migrations and seeds has outdated default columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a rake task that runs migrations and seeds from multiple engines. I have been getting errors where the seeds are trying to create objects with nil columns for fields that have since been migrated away.

I inserted a debugger line in the seed file and ran the following commands:

```
>Document::Work.column_defaults
{"id"=>nil,
 "abstract"=>nil,
 "created_at"=>nil,
 "updated_at"=>nil,
 "work_type_id"=>nil}

>Document::Work.reset_column_information
nil

>Document::Work.column_defaults
{"id"=>nil,
 "created_at"=>nil,
 "updated_at"=>nil,
 "work_type_id"=>nil,
 "creator_id"=>nil}
```

Is there a way I can refresh the environment, or will I need to call reset_column_information in all my seed files?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to do it once. Immediately after you remove the column.

Comment: I should have been clearer in the description of the issue, i have a similar problem happening in a few different models. I ended up just separating the migration and seed tasks.